# Less css selector issue

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I am using less css and trying to use & for combining multiple selectors. I have created a dummy environment to elaborate the issue.

**HTML**

```
<div class="ampuse">
    <p>This is first</p>
    <p>This is second</p>
    <div>This is div 1</div>
    <p>This is Third</p>
    <em>This is em</em>
    <div>This is div 2</div>
    <div>This is div 3</div>
</div>
```

**LESS**

```
.ampuse{
    p,div{
        color: red;
        &+&{
            background: yellow;
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Now according to less rules this will create the css like this

```
.ampuse p,
.ampuse div {
  color: red;
}

.ampuse p + .ampuse p,
.ampuse p + .ampuse div,
.ampuse div + .ampuse p,
.ampuse div + .ampuse div {
  background: yellow;
  color: blue;
}
```

But i want to render the parent only once and then selector should work under children element. This is the css i want

```
.ampuse p,
.ampuse div {
  color: red;
}

.ampuse p + p,
.ampuse p + div,
.ampuse div + p,
.ampuse div + div {
  background: yellow;
  color: blue;
}
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve it with less?

Comment: Have you tried `& + p, & + div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer to accept* as stated in my comment, use `& + p, & + div`

```
.ampuse{
    p,div{
        color: red;

        + p,
        + div {
            background: yellow;
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i am bit confused how this is working as when we are using `&+&` it means it will make all the comparisons of `p,div` but `&+p, &+div`? How it is creating the instances?

Comment: @GauravAggarwal It is making compositions of selectors, but `&` means `parent from top level`, witch is `.ampuse p/div` that's why `&+&` leads to `.ampuse p + .ampuse p`

Comment: @TheReveller My answer is at comments, moved it to real answer, your answer is after mine comment, maybe that's why OP accepted it.

Answer (score 2):

```
.ampuse {
    p,
    div {color: red;
        + p,
        + div {
          background: yellow;
          color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Makes

```
.ampuse p,
.ampuse div {
  color: red;
}
.ampuse p + p,
.ampuse div + p,
.ampuse p + div,
.ampuse div + div {
  background: yellow;
  color: blue;
}
```